# php.ini problem while installing composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Please, can someone help me?
Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v8.65.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev].
- league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.65 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.65.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\Program Files (x86)\php-8.1\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you don't have the `fileinfo` extension installed/enabled for the CLI configuration of PHP it would seem

Comment: find the `fileinfo` extension by searching it in your php.ini inside your CLI, then remove the starting `;` from that line to enable it